# Number of arrangements with no consecutive letter the same - without using Jair Taylor's formula

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

This is continuation to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040508/number-of-arrangements-with-no-consecutive-letter-the-same). I find that complexity of this problem increases as the number of repeating letters increases. For example, consider the below problem.

> How many arrangements of the letters in the word PQRDDDEEEEFFFFF have no
>   consecutive letter the same?

Note:I have gone through all similar problems here and well aware of the common methods used. However, I could not apply any of the methods learned for the above problem. Please help, how to solve the above problem without using  Jair Taylor's formula.

Comment: Similar question found (for the word KOMBINATOORIKA)  at https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Permutations/Permutations.faq.question.941398.html but not solution given.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of search, I came across this [tool in careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/calculators/word/index.php)  and using that I solved both the problems. Posting it here for other readers benefit.

**Question $1.$**

> Number of arrangements using the word 'PQRDDDEEEEFFFFF' having no consecutive letters the same

**Answer Generated Using The [Tool](http://www.careerbless.com/calculators/word/index.php) is $3659160$ with the following explanation**
(see question no.$23$ in the generated question list after entering the word 'PQRDDDEEEEFFFFF')

> [image]

**Question $2.$**

> Number of arrangements using the word 'KOMBINATOORIKA' having no consecutive letters the same

**Answer Generated Using The [Tool](http://www.careerbless.com/calculators/word/index.php) is $710579520$**
(see question no.$24$ in the generated question list after entering the word 'KOMBINATOORIKA') (explanation is very lengthy as the previous one and not posting it here)